# rigging with inverse kinematic

Tags: animation, rigging, inverse-kinematics

I would like to encourage a movement for this model. Does it make sense to use inverse kinematics here? How should I proceed here?
I have already tried to recreate this with bones, hopefully it will work.

[image: armature]

and here is the model i want to animate. First the startposition and second picture is how it will look when i rotate first bone around y.

[image: start]

[image: after rotation]

how can i animate this movement? I need inverse kinematic right?

Comment: please add a link to an animation/video how it should work. Your two small pics doesn't make it clear to me how the animation should be.

Comment: https://youtube.com/shorts/NI7p6CnXp1E?si=yQzRldTE_df5zGFI